# Struts2 - Iterating over embedded object lists in JSP

Tags: struts2

I have a class on the value stack that contains a list of objects, each object is another list of objects and finally there is the object I want to access. For Example:

FruitGroupsList-->FruitGroup-->Fruit

Let's say FruitGroupsList contains 2 FruitGroup Lists:

1. EdibleFruits
2. NonEdibleFruits

The EdibleFruits is a FruitGroup (list) that contains a bunch of Fruit Objects:

1. Apple
2. Pear
3. Plum
   ...

Each Fruit has a Name property.

I understand that I can Iterate through the FruitGroupsList like so:

```
<s:iterator value="FruitGroupsList" var="fgl">   
  <s:property value="%{#fgl.name}" />
</s:iterator>
```

How do I loop through each FruitGroup and get a property (such as FruitName)? I've tried various types of embedding other iterator tags but thus far I can't seem to solve this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you've only put one type in each list, otherwise you should really use a map.

So your veiw has access to your actions:

```
List<List<Fruit>> fruitGroupsList;
```

In which case you'd say:

```
<s:iterator value="fruitGroupsList">   
  <s:iterator>
    <s:property value="whatEverPropertyAFruitHas"/> <!-- If this was a simple type such as String, you could just write <s:property/>
  </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

A list of lists requires two iterators. If things get more confusing then putting a getter in the action to extract some deeply nested items might be reasonable.

Comment: The code above has been tested to work.  The code before worked but was a little more complicated (a var attribute was used which was not needed), if you still can't get it working show your action so the solution can be exact.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed myself. there was issue in Setter and getter of action class